# jQuery for HTML to PHP - Function Error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have just purchased "Tonic Gallery" which my client thinks it's absolutely perfect for his website. The difficulty is that it works great with HTML but for ".php" it won't even load.

To give you a better idea, here two links:

Tonic Gallery Link: http://codecanyon.net/item/tonic-gal...gallery/120710

LincHospitality.com: http://linchospitality.com/

This is inputed into the "Portfolio" tab. As per instructions, I have entered the following into the "head" (header.php):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/tonic_gallery.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/demo_styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/prettyPhoto.css"/>


<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/portfolio-setter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
        // init the portfolio functionality
        $('#portfolio_wavy').portfolioSetter({xmlSource:'portfolio.xml', wavyAnimation:true});

  });
</script>
```

I had then created the "portfolio.php" page with the required input from the plugin:

```
<?php $page = "portfolio";?> 
<?php include("header.php"); ?> 

  <div role="main"> 
    <div class="wrapper" id="subPagesWrap"> 
    <div id="portfolio_wavy"></div> 
    </div><!-- wrapper --> 
  </div> <!-- end main --> 

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

The in a direct ".html" file, it works perfectly! But since I had placed in the "header.php" and "portfolio.php", I get the following error:

```
$("#portfolio_wavy").portfolioSetter is not a function
```

Here is a link to the ".html" files as to how it's suppose to work. Same functions, same root folder just not working in ".php".

linchospitality "/" gallery [dot] html

How do I over come this function error?  Any simple methods?

Thanks!

Comment: You are loading jQuery twice on the PHP page (Version 1.4 in the head, and 1.7 in the footer). That's bound to cause trouble.

Comment: jQuery is a new world to me, would be a safe bet to delete the loader in the footer and place it in the header while removing the 1.4 verson?

Comment: Thanks for the catch there.  I removed the the 1.4 but it looks like I have some cleaning up to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the function after it has loaded. You can make sure of this by running it on the document ready event. I am not sure of the syntax you are using, but just make sure that it is run after the document ready is fired.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  jQuery is something I am dabbling in for the first time. Would you have any suggestions on how I can do that or what sources I could look into?

Comment: sorry, just ready over again. I'll check into the doc ready event.

Comment: So by performing the doc ready event, would the code rewritten look like this?$(document).ready($(function(){
  $('#portfolio_wavy').portfolioSetter({xmlSource:'portfolio.xml', wavyAnimation:true});
 }));

Comment: I figured it out!  Thanks for pointing the way!  Your tip helped! :)  If was wasn't so young to the forum I would vote your answer up!  Thank you!

Comment: Great! so I will just delete the document then if it's not needed, it was really js conflict and where the both of them were being loaded.

Comment: @Pekka - just by removing the document, I saw more improvement, thank you!